# How to set the module name when extracting Coq to Haskell

Tags: haskell, coq, coq-extraction

When I extract/compile Coq to Haskell using `Extraction Language Haskell.` in the Coq file and running `coqtop -compile mymodule.v > MyModule.hs`, I get a Haskell module which starts with `module Main where`.

Is there an option to set the resulting Haskell module name?

I currently pipe to sed like this -

```
coqtop -compile mymodule.v | sed s/Main/MyModule/ > MyModule.hs
```

but I'm looking for a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Extraction "file"` or `Extraction Library` (or its variants), e.g.

```
Definition foo := 6*7.

Extraction Language Haskell.
Extraction "MyModule" foo.
```

The above produces `MyModule.hs` file, which starts with `module MyModule where`.